# Installing Hadoop on MacOS resulting in build failure with CMake

Tags: java, hadoop, cmake

I am trying to build the hadoop native for the first time as given below

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.3:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: Error executing CMake: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "/Users/krishnanand/projects/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.3:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: Error executing CMake
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing CMake
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.runCMake(CompileMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.execute(CompileMojo.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "/Users/krishnanand/projects/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.runCMake(CompileMojo.java:166)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

The [requirements](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt) to build the native code states that CMake v3.1 is required. I have installed CMake with brew and my list of installed packages is given below

```
hadoop (release_3_0_3) $ brew list
autoconf    cmake       gzip        libtool     protobuf@2.5
automake    gcc     isl     mpfr        snappy
bzip2       gmp     libmpc      openssl     zlib
```

More information about cmake

```
hadoop (release_3_0_3) $ brew list cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/bin/ccmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/bin/cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/bin/cmakexbuild
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/bin/cpack
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/bin/ctest
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/aclocal/cmake.m4
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/cmake/ (2376 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/doc/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake/cmake-mode.el
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/man/ (20 files)
```

I am trying to install Hadoop v3.0.3. Any help would be gratefully appreicated.

Comment: I think you've cut off the actual error in your question here because Cmake ran, but it threw an error. That link also says to use docker machine on a Mac

Comment: @cricket_007 I have pasted the entire stacktrace here.

Comment: Okay, well it's saying `no such file or directory`, but you seem to be missing the instructions that say if using a Mac, to use Docker Machine

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: found any solutions guys for macos high sierra?